# Ignition Fortress shows a black screen where the scene should be with OpenGL 4.5 on Docker on AWS

Tags: ignition-fortress, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I've been trying to make Ignition Fortress work on Docker, but I am having some errors.

I initially installed it using **apt-get** on a **Ubuntu 20.04**, but when running `ign gazebo shapes.sdf -v4`, it says

> OpenGL 3.3 is not supported. Please update your graphics card drivers

I then upgraded `OpenGL to 4.5`, but there is always a black screen in the place where the scene should be.

I then installed with **apt-get on Ubuntu 22.04** but I still have the same black screen, although I do not have the OpenGL error because OpenGL is already `OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.1`

I then installed `Ignition Fortress` from source, but I still have the black screen.

I've been checking the logs but the only warns I find are like the ones below:

```
[Dbg] [ServerConfig.cc:973] Loaded (3) plugins from file [/home/user/.ignition/gazebo/6/server.config]
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:763] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:112:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:763] [QT] qrc:/qml/StyleDialog.qml:105:3: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
```

and

```
[GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v125WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Ogre2RenderTarget.cc:575] Anti-aliasing level of '8' is not supported; valid FSAA levels are: [ 0 4 ]. Setting to 0
```

If I run **Gazebo Classic**, I have no black screens, but it always happens with **Ignition Fortress, be it installed with apt-get or from source**.

Does anybody have any ideas why this could be happening and how to solve it?

If I install Ignition Fortress on my local PC (rather than in a Docker container), it works, butt on Docker it always fails.

Below we have a gif of the error:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28144/ignition-fortress-shows-a-black-screen-where-the-scene-should-be-with-opengl-4.5-on-docker-on-aws/) by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Led by [a similar issue](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox/issues/383), I mounted the `/dev` folder of the Docker host inside the container and, as if by **miracle**, Ignition Fortress loaded with no black screen.

I then compared the logs of when it worked and when it didn't, and I found the following error message when it does not work:

```
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
libGL error: glx: failed to create dri3 screen
libGL error: failed to load driver: crocus
libGL error: failed to open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
```

Then, instead of mounting the whole `/dev` inside the container, I mounted only the `/dev/dri` folder and everything worked just nice.

Awesome!!!

Below is the `docker-compose.yaml` file used for testing:

```
version: '3'

services:
  fortress:
    image: my-docker-image/with-ignition:fortress  # Put your image name here
    container_name: fortress
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=:0
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
      - /dev/dri:/dev/dri
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
    command:
      - ign gazebo shapes.sdf -v4
```

Of course, before running `docker-compose up`, I had to run  `xhost +local:root` to make the Graphical apps from the docker container appear on my desktop.

It is worth mentioning that sharing `/dev/dri` worked on my local computer. When trying the same on AWS, the black screen was still there.

## On AWS with OpenGL 3.3 and Ogre1

In order to make it work on AWS, I had to:

- Keep OpenGL 3.3
- Use the `--render-engine ogre` param to force Ignition to use `Ogre 1`, following instructions on ignition [troubleshooting](https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/troubleshooting#unable-to-create-the-rendering-window)

## On AWS with Ogre2 and OpenGL 4.5

To make it work with Ogre2 `--render-engine ogre2`, I had to compile it from the source after **disabling Anti-Aliasing**.

The steps were detailed on [this issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1116#issuecomment-1142388038)

I first upgraded OpenGL using [these instructions](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/install-latest-mesa-ubuntu-20-04-21-04/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y full-upgrade
```

Then

- I followed the instructions on how to build from source (https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/install_ubuntu_src)
- BUT, instead of using the collection-fortress.yaml of the tutorial, I used a custom one, [shown in the issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1116#issuecomment-1142388038). I did not paste the custom YAML file here because I could not format it properly.

Then the Black Screen went away for me.

---

> My people are destroyed from lack of knowledge.
>
> Hosea 4:6 (part a)

---

Originally posted by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1315/ruffsl/) on 2023-04-04**:
Did you ever figure out the root cause of this? I've just encountered a similar issue using rviz2 on ROS Rolling with Ubuntu Jammy. Your use `-v - /dev/dri:/dev/dri` also resolved my issue with `libGL error: glx: failed to create dri3 screen`.

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2023-06-09**:
Hi @ruffsl, only today I saw your comment.

I couldn't find the root cause back then, but today I had the same problem when upgrading Humble. I solved upgrading Mesa, as explained on https://github.com/ros2/rviz/issues/948#issuecomment-1427569107:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Today my problem was with both rviz2 and gazebo

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Look this](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1116#issuecomment-1136897838), well no need to upgrade mesa to 22 from other repos, just mention 
 **`-e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all`**  in your docker command, (it allows docker container to use OpenGL) after that you can use ogre2 with hardware rendering, no black screen, no other Environment exports ! 
ofcurse you should be able to use gpu in docker which itself needs (Nvidia-container-toolkit / Nvidia-container-runtime2 / Nvidia-container-runtime), Nvidia-container-toolkit is preferred,
here is the command I use to run the docker image:

docker run --gpus all --ipc host --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=6718864 \
-e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all \
-it --net=host \
-v "$HOME/container_test/":/workspace -w /workspace \  
-v /dev:/dev --privileged \  
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} \
--name ignition_fortress \
IMAGE

---

Originally posted by [rubar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87538/rubar/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2931/ruben/) on 2022-05-31**:
I tried exporting this **`NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all`** variable, but it was not able to completely solve the problem.
I updated my answer. After disabling Anti-Aliasing and compiling Ignition Fortress from source, it worked.